# Add recipient to Woocommerce New Order notification based on order item categories

Tags: email, woocommerce

I am programatically creating a product category when I add a new user. I am also saving that new category ID to the user meta and the new user ID to the category meta. Every category has an associated user, and every user has an associated product category. I have other functions using this association successfully to accomplish various things.

```
// for reference only:
update_term_meta( $cat_id, 'user_id', $user_id );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'cat_id', $cat_id );
```

Every product is in one product category and every product category has the term meta 'user_id' defined.

When a new order notification is triggered in Woocommerce, I need to add a recipient to it based on the product categories associated with each order item. For some reason, my function is not working. No recipients are ever added. Here's the function in question:

```
function maybe_add_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) return $recipient;

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $items ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $items->get_product_id(), 'product_cat' );

        foreach( $terms as $wp_term ){
            $user_id = get_term_meta($wp_term->term_id, 'user_id');
            $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
            $user_email = $user_info->user_email;

            $recipient .= ','.$user_email;
        }
    }

    return $recipient;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'maybe_add_new_order_email_recipient', 1, 2);
```

What am I missing here!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself... after a little extra investigation. `get_term_meta` was returning an array, so `get_userdata($user_id[0])` was required. Here's the fully working function:

```
function maybe_add_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) return $recipient;

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $items ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $items->get_product_id(), 'product_cat' );

        foreach( $terms as $wp_term ){
            $user_id = get_term_meta($wp_term->term_id, 'user_id');
            $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id[0] );
            $user_email = $user_info->user_email;

            $recipient .= ','.$user_email;
        }
    }

    return $recipient;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'maybe_add_new_order_email_recipient', 1, 2);
```